# Stop one javascript file from executing, from a different javascript file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, volusion

Is it possible to stop one javascript file from executing from a different javascript file?

Eg.

**HTML**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>jQuery UI Dialog functionality</title>
      <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
      <!-- CSS -->

      <!-- Javascript -->
      <script src="checkout.js"></script>
      <script src="dummy.js"></script>

   </head>
   <body>
      Pickup Date: <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Orders.Custom_Field_PickupDate" value=""> 
      <br />
      Return Date: <input type="text" maxlength="10" name="Orders.Custom_Field_ReturnDate" value=""> 
      <br />

        <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" bgcolor="#EEEEEE" id="table_checkout_cart0">
            <tr>
                <td align="left">
                    <br>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> <span id="span_Shopping_Cart_UnEditable">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1" id="v65-onepage-CartSummary">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <table id="v65-onepage-ordersummary-items" border=0 cellpadding=2 cellspacing=1 width="580"><tr id="v65-onepage-ordersummary-header-row">
                                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemcode v65-onepage-ordersummary-header" style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">
                                    Code
                                </td>
                                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemname v65-onepage-ordersummary-header" style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">
                                    Name
                                </td>
                                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemprice v65-onepage-ordersummary-header" style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">
                                    Price
                                </td>
                                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemqty v65-onepage-ordersummary-header" style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">
                                    Qty
                                </td>
                                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemtotal v65-onepage-ordersummary-header" style="color:#000000;font-weight:bold">
                                    Total
                                </td>
                    </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemcode" style="color:#666666">
                    K10306
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemname" style="color:#666666">
                    MYT Works 4ft Large Slider Kit
                </td><td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemprice" style="color:#666666">
                    $160.00
                    <br />
                    exc Tax
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemqty" style="color:#666666">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemtotal" style="color:#666666">
                    $160.00
                    <br />10% Tax = $16.00
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemcode" style="color:#666666">
                    C10881
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemname" style="color:#666666">
                    Apurture V-Control USB Remote Focus
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemprice" style="color:#666666">
                    $18.00
                    <br />
                    exc Tax
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemqty" style="color:#666666">
                    1
                </td>
                <td class="v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemtotal" style="color:#666666">
                    $18.00
                    <br />
                    10% Tax = $1.80
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>


      <div id="IncompletePickupDate-Dialog" title="Incomplete Pickup Date">Please enter pickup date.</div>
      <div id="IncompleteReturnDate-Dialog" title="Incomplete Return Date">Please enter return date.</div>
      <br />
      <input type="button" value="Place Order" id="btnSubmitOrder">
      <br />


   </body>
</html>
```

**JS 01 - checkout.js**

```
function checkItems() {
    var returnValue = 0;
    $('#v65-onepage-ordersummary-items tr').each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        var code = $.trim($this.find(".v65-onepage-ordersummary-itemcode").html());
        if ( code.charAt(0) == 'K' ) {
            returnValue = 1;
            return false; 
        }
    });
    return returnValue;
}

$(function() {
    $('input[name="Orders.Custom_Field_PickupDate"]').datepicker({
         dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy', showButtonPanel: true
    });
    $('input[name="Orders.Custom_Field_ReturnDate"]').datepicker({
         dateFormat:'dd/mm/yy', showButtonPanel: true
    });
    $( "#IncompletePickupDate-Dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
    });
    $( "#IncompleteReturnDate-Dialog").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,  
    });  
    $( "#btnSubmitOrder" ).click(function(e) {
        var pickupDate = $('input[name="Orders.Custom_Field_PickupDate"]').val().length;
        var returnDate = $('input[name="Orders.Custom_Field_ReturnDate"]').val().length;
        if (checkItems()) {
            if (pickupDate == 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $( "#IncompletePickupDate-Dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            }
            else if (returnDate == 0) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $( "#IncompleteReturnDate-Dialog" ).dialog( "open" );
            }
        }   
        if ((pickupDate !=0 && returnDate != 0) || checkItems() == 0) {
            // TODO: Direct to Complete.html which displays just text saying Done.
        }
        console.log(checkItems());
    });
});
```

**JS 02 - dummy.js**

```
$(function() {
    $( "#btnSubmitOrder" ).click(function(e) {
        window.location.replace("http://www.google.com");
    });
});
```

**What I want to do** is, if pickupDate or returnDate is equal to zero (code in checkout.js), I want to stop all javascript files from running, and I don't want dummy.js to execute. If pickupDate and returnDate are not equal to 0, then I want to continue with the execution.

I am trying to help a friend during my uni break on his website. I can't combine the two files because the software is proprietary software, and there are a lot of limitations. I can't edit their code because it is hard coded, but I can upload html, css, javascript or jQuery files.

On his website he sells and rents products - all rental products start with the letter "K", and all sale products start with something else. On his checkout page he currently has to enter a pickup date and return date for sale and rental products, but he only wants users to enter pickup or return date for rental products.

The code I wrote above only executes when the "btnSubmitOrder" is clicked, and currently there is default functionality for this button, which I do not have access to.
So to achieve this, I thought about putting a javascript file above the default functionality, and attempt **what I want to do**.

Note: Files above are just some testing I'm doing locally, the real files are too large to paste here.

If this does not make sense, or more info is required please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have a look into `require.js` which is perfect for your scenario. Although suggestion is load scripts dynamically whereever it is required with `$.getScript()` or just use `.append()` to head.

Comment: Generally speaking you can't "stop executing" javascript file. As soon as it was loaded and evaluated all the side-effects are done: global variables are set, event listeners are added etc. You could either conditionally load file (thus preventing some from being evaluated) or remove all the side effects (which is hard and not always possible).

Comment: Just as Yury Tarabanko and Jai said, you should think about dynamically loading the JS file if you need it. As a workaround, which is not beautiful but would work, you could declare a global variable and check whether it's true or false in your script.